# html5 kineticjs with free transform save image to web service

Tags: image, html, save, transform, kineticjs

I need to use kinetic in order to transform one image using the anchors. I found this example:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/

I then need to save just one image - the yoda image (id: myImg) and send off to a web service. I'm having trouble with the saving portion.

Can anyone help? I'm not sure everything is correct, as I'm getting this error on when btnsave - Object #Class has no method 'replace' index.html:187

### code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      canvas {
        border: 1px solid #9C9898;
      }
    </style>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.0.0.js"></script>
    <script>
      function update(group, activeAnchor) {
        var topLeft = group.get(".topLeft")[0];
        var topRight = group.get(".topRight")[0];
        var bottomRight = group.get(".bottomRight")[0];
        var bottomLeft = group.get(".bottomLeft")[0];
        var image = group.get(".image")[0];

        // update anchor positions
        switch (activeAnchor.getName()) {
          case "topLeft":
            topRight.attrs.y = activeAnchor.attrs.y;
            bottomLeft.attrs.x = activeAnchor.attrs.x;
            break;
          case "topRight":
            topLeft.attrs.y = activeAnchor.attrs.y;
            bottomRight.attrs.x = activeAnchor.attrs.x;
            break;
          case "bottomRight":
            bottomLeft.attrs.y = activeAnchor.attrs.y;
            topRight.attrs.x = activeAnchor.attrs.x;
            break;
          case "bottomLeft":
            bottomRight.attrs.y = activeAnchor.attrs.y;
            topLeft.attrs.x = activeAnchor.attrs.x;
            break;
        }

        image.setPosition(topLeft.attrs.x, topLeft.attrs.y);

        var width = topRight.attrs.x - topLeft.attrs.x;
        var height = bottomLeft.attrs.y - topLeft.attrs.y;
        if(width && height) {
          image.setSize(width, height);
        }
      }
      function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
        var stage = group.getStage();
        var layer = group.getLayer();

        var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
          x: x,
          y: y,
          stroke: "#666",
          fill: "#ddd",
          strokeWidth: 2,
          radius: 8,
          name: name,
          draggable: true
        });

        anchor.on("dragmove", function() {
          update(group, this);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on("mousedown touchstart", function() {
          group.setDraggable(false);
          this.moveToTop();
        });
        anchor.on("dragend", function() {
          group.setDraggable(true);
          layer.draw();
        });
        // add hover styling
        anchor.on("mouseover", function() {
          var layer = this.getLayer();
          document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
          this.setStrokeWidth(4);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on("mouseout", function() {
          var layer = this.getLayer();
          document.body.style.cursor = "default";
          this.setStrokeWidth(2);
          layer.draw();
        });

        group.add(anchor);
      }
      function loadImages(sources, callback) {
        var images = {};
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var numImages = 0;
        for(var src in sources) {
          numImages++;
        }
        for(var src in sources) {
          images[src] = new Image();
          images[src].onload = function() {
            if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
              callback(images);
            }
          };
          images[src].src = sources[src];
        }
      }
      function initStage(images) {
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: "container",
          width: 578,
          height: 400
        });
        var darthVaderGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
          x: 270,
          y: 100,
          draggable: true
        });
        var yodaGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
          x: 100,
          y: 110,
          draggable: true
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        /*
         * go ahead and add the groups
         * to the layer and the layer to the
         * stage so that the groups have knowledge
         * of its layer and stage
         */
        layer.add(darthVaderGroup);
        layer.add(yodaGroup);
        stage.add(layer);

        // darth vader
        var darthVaderImg = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          image: images.darthVader,
          width: 200,
          height: 138,
          name: "image"
        });

        darthVaderGroup.add(darthVaderImg);
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 0, 0, "topLeft");
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 200, 0, "topRight");
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 200, 138, "bottomRight");
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 0, 138, "bottomLeft");

        darthVaderGroup.on("dragstart", function() {
          this.moveToTop();
        });
        // yoda
        var yodaImg = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          image: images.yoda,
          width: 93,
          height: 104,
          name: "image",
      id: "myImg"
        });

        yodaGroup.add(yodaImg);
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 0, 0, "topLeft");
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 93, 0, "topRight");
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 93, 104, "bottomRight");
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 0, 104, "bottomLeft");

        yodaGroup.on("dragstart", function() {
          this.moveToTop();
        });

        stage.draw();

            $("#btnSave").click(function () {
                var image = stage.get("#myImg")[0];
                 image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');

                 $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url:  domain + '/Services/WS.asmx/UploadImage',
                    data: '{ "imageData" : "' + image + '" }',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (msg) {
                       alert(msg.d);
                    }
                 });
              });   
      }

      window.onload = function() {
        var sources = {
          darthVader: "http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg",
          yoda: "http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg"
        };
        loadImages(sources, initStage);
      };

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onmousedown="return false;">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <input type="button" id="btnSave" name="btnSave" value="Save the canvas to server" />

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to stringify everything,

For example:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/WS/SaveObject.asmx/fSaveToDB"),
        data: JSON.stringify({ _obj: this }),
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

I had a huge problem before myself, started to work after i stringified it